Best practice to index an array inside an entity
I'm currently ingesting data to elasticsearch through logstash from SQL.
The entity that i'm currently working with has a list of Tags that is basically a list of ids. in the logstash pipe i have the following in the input
statement => " SELECT 
  p.*
  STRING_AGG(pt.TagId, ',') AS Tags 
FROM 
  Products p   
  LEFT JOIN ProductTags pt ON p.Id = pt.ProductId 
GROUP BY 
  p.*

and in the filter
filter {
    mutate {
        split => { "Tags" => "," }
    }
    mutate {
        convert => { "Tags" => "integer" }
    }
}

in kibana, the Tags field is an Integer and in the json looks like this.
 "Tags": [
      6,
      772,
      777
    ],

The idea is that in my app, i'll allow to filter by tags, so i would be doing search by Tag ids.
I saw a post that said that in case of looking for specific numbers (This is not a range query), it would be better to make this array as an array of strings due to the keywords. Is this true? Is it better to keep them as an array of strings instead of an array of integers?
Thanks!

If you know you are only going to do term queries (and not range queries) then it is better to map numbers as keywords because the query will be better optimized. This is explicitly documented by elastic here.
